# Best way to write unit test for Node Rest api while working with Postgres, chai and mocha?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am working on node js rest api in which database is Postgres and we are not using any ORM. How I am writing is as below which is hitting database for create and update

```
it('it should create customer', (done) => {
  const payload = {
    customerId: "test",
    customerName: "test",
    customerAddress: "Some place, NWZ"
  }
  chai
    .request(server)
    .post('/customer')
    .send(payload)
    .end((err, res) => {
      res.should.have.status(200);
      res.body.success.should.equal(true);
      done();
    });
});
```

Now I want to know that **what is best way** to write unit test cases ? Like

1. Should I write unit test cases by mocking api response excluding database query ?
2. Or should I write unit test case which will hit database ?

Or in any way we can mock database ? What is best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some debate regarding whether unit tests should hit database. But in general, I would say hitting a real database in testing should be categories as integration test, not unit test.

So for your question 2: I would say: no, you should not write unit test case that hit database.

Then for your question 1: yes, you should mocking api response, the library you could choose, e.g. sinon.

---- Updated ----

There is an article regarding the topic, if you are interested, please refer to the following: [Hitting Real Database? Unit Test and Integration Test for RESTful API in Nodejs Environment](https://www.jingjies-blog.com/blog/2022/08/03/ut-it-restful-api-in-nodejs/https://)